# Xamarin.Forms: TabbedPage icons are good on Android but way too big on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have in my tabbed list three content pages, all of them have a menu at the bottom which you can click and it also has an icon in there. Whil on android, the icons look just fine in size on iOS they look like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is the xaml code:

```
    <ContentPage Title="Abgelehnt" 
                 BackgroundColor="#e1e1e1"
                 x:Name="tab1_tabbedlist_history" 
                 IconImageSource="icon_cross" >

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTTST.png
```

As you can see, I am not even adding any sizes to them. Why are they SO DAMN HUGE?

```
This is the tabbed Page:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
                 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
                mc:Ignorable="d"        
                             BackgroundColor="#ffffff"
                 x:Class="App4.Screens.ScrollViews.Screen_TabbedLists">
      <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->

<ContentPage...>

</TabbedPage>
```

There are no custrom renderers to it...

Comment: Do you have any TabbedPageRenderers? Also, please provide the full xaml for the TabPage, because there may be some configurations there too.

Comment: @MihailDuchev heya, i updated the qeustsions. thank yoiu!

Comment: are you following the Apple guidelines on icon sizing?  https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Comment: You could check my answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Jason said, the best way is to follow the guidelines of icon size in iOS . However , if you do want to use the image with bigger size , you could re-set the size in iOS platform by using **CustomRenderer** .

#### in iOS Project

```
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage),typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer :TabbedRenderer
    {

        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
            {
                item.Image = ScalingImageToSize(item.Image, new CGSize(30, 30)); // set the size here as you want 
            }
        }



        public UIImage ScalingImageToSize(UIImage sourceImage, CGSize newSize)
        {

            if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 2.0) //@2x iPhone 6 7 8 
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 2.0f);
            }


            else if (UIScreen.MainScreen.Scale == 3.0) //@3x iPhone 6p 7p 8p...
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 3.0f);
            }

            else
            {
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(newSize);
            }

            sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height));

            UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            return newImage;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do I only need this on class or do I also need these handler classes ?

Comment: You just need to add the class in your iOS project .

Comment: Wow, I dont really get how, but this worked SO GOOD! thank you my friend SO MUCH!

Comment: Zhang, I noticed a problem, where the button that is clicked on SOME iPhones is still being huge, only the greyed out ones are in normal size, Do you maybe know where ithis is coming from?

Comment: What is the version of the device？

Comment: one edit id like to make: replace sourceImage.draw with: if(sourceImage != null)
                sourceImage.Draw(new CGRect(0, 0, newSize.Width, newSize.Height)); otherwise this could lead into crashes